# How can I encrypt a file in AES's EAX mode?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

Is there a Python library which supports AES EAX mode? [PyCrypto](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto) doesn't seem to support it.

Is there a reason *why* it doesn't seem to be supported?

Comment: I think that it is because this a very general question. `Stackoverflow` is normally used for code specific questions. Take a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It is a code specific question: `How can I encrypt a file in AES's EAX mode?` If someone asked how to use `hashlib` in Python, it wouldn't be downvoted into oblivion, why downvote this question?

Comment: You will need to check with the authors. I am sure they simply haven't had time. Maybe you can contribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you take a look at [this](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyTomCrypt) [LibTomCrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features) wrapper. It should support what you need.

Comment: Most of the times when I Google something coding related I end up here anyway. :p

Comment: Well, now they will for this question :)

Comment: Any idea why PyCrypto doesn't support GCM and EAX?

Comment: GCM and EAX mode generally receive too little attention. Nobody can answer your question for sure except the authors of PyCrypto of course.

Answer (score 2):

EAX (and others AEAD modes like GCM, CCM and SIV) will be soon supported in version 2.7 of PyCrypto.

Right now, on the [PyCrypto website](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) there is an alpha version available for download. Alternatively, you can check out the current master branch on [github](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto).